# Upload in wysiwyg not working anymore

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, file-upload

i have this:

[image]

After clicking open, nothing happens. Clicking Upload Files does nothing too then.

There are no errors in the console at any time.

The Uploader works on Produktpages.

What can i do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the permission of media folder, and also check for wysiwyg folder exists in media folder if not create it and make it's permission as 777.

Comment: I have checked the permissions, they are all on 777 in media and him self. 
The folder exsists, it was working for some time.